# Como puedo obtener un parametro que proviene del metodo get desde el archivo controllers en php

Tags: php

Tengo esta url el cual manda el parametro id por medio del metodo get, pero cuando quiero recibirlo por medio del controlador, me dice que no exite.

> http://localhost/curso-php/databases/public/list/update/?id=1

```
 public function getUpdate(){

        global $pdo;
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id";
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $query->execute([
            'id' => $id
        ]);

        $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $nameValue = $row['name'];
        $emailValue = $row['email'];

        return render('../views/admin/update.php', ['nameValue'=>$nameValue, 'emailValue'=>$emailValue]);

    }
```

Luego me arroha esto

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso-php/databases/app/control/admin/usersControl.php
>   on line 21

Comment: Cuál es la línea 21 del error en el trozo de código que has puesto?

Comment: es la que dice:         $id = $_GET['id']; que es por que no encuentra el id y pues no se como pasar el id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Si usas un Framework el método GET se recoge de forma diferente. Lee la documentación en la pagina oficial.

Si usas Symfony aquí esta lo que necesitas: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object

Si usas Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Si quieres recibir parámetros, piensa que el navegador hace una petición al servidor. Eso es una request.

> Puedes tratar las request y imprimirlos por pantalla con
>   var_dump($request->query->get('id'));die;
>    die termina el script y retorna al navegador el var_dump en texto.

De todas maneras para poder recoger el id de una url bonita necesitas declararlo en el Routing y le pasas el id por parámetro a la función.

```
//Incluye el paquete que se encarga de las peticiones al principio del controlador
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="message")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template("ExampleBundle:Message:edit.html.twig")
 */

public function createAction(Request $request, $id){
   $valor = $request->query->get('id');
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html
- Si no lo haces con ningún framework usa var_dump($_GET) haber que te devuelve

Answer (score 0):

si haces esto en la pagina donde este el formulario

```
<?php
<form method="get" action="urlalaqueloenvias.php">
Introduce un nombre <input name="nombre" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
?>
```

Y esto otro en la pagina que lo recibe:

```
<?php
$variable=$:GET["nombre"];
echo $variable;
?>
```

Deberia de funcionar ahora lo que no entiendo yo es si pones Ñ o á o é o í porque no                 funciona se tiene el metacharset en uft-8 o como es mi caso que en la URL ya viene mal   el nombre con caracteres especiales, a ver si alguien me lo aclara.